# Binary Guid in SQLite [ PetaPoco MicroOrm ]

Tags: sqlite, petapoco

When I try to insert a record with Guid into SQLite, 
PetaPoco insert that guid as a string not binary...
In my connection string to SQLite i identify BinaryGUID=True.

Why this happen and how can I  force PetaPoco write Guid as binary?

**UPDATE: I Find it...**

Thanks for "Open Source Movement"...:-)

I check the source code and see that there is a code like this at AddParam:

```
else if (t == typeof(Guid))
{
    p.Value = item.ToString();
    p.DbType = DbType.String;
    p.Size = 40;
}
```

and changed it to Guid

```
else if (t == typeof(Guid))
{
    p.Value = item;
    p.DbType = DbType.Guid;
    p.Size = 40;
}
```